# In gamemaker studio, how do I make text boxes?

Tags: game-maker, text

How to make text boxes in gamemaker studio?

Comment: You mean, just plain text to read, or a place to input text?

Answer (score 2):

There are the built-in functions to show textboxes to the user:

- Read strings or integer from the user:

  - [`get_string(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/debugging/get_string.html) (for debug purpose only)
  - [`get_string_async(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/asynchronous%20functions/get_string_async.html)
  - [`get_integer(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/debugging/get_integer.html) (for debug purpose only)
  - [`get_integer_async(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/asynchronous%20functions/get_integer_async.html)
- Show a dialog to load and save files:

  - [`get_save_filename(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/file%20handling/file%20system/get_save_filename.html) and [`get_save_filename_ext(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/file%20handling/file%20system/get_save_filename_ext.html)
  - [`get_open_filename(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/file%20handling/file%20system/get_open_filename.html) and [`get_open_filename_ext(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/file%20handling/file%20system/get_open_filename_ext.html)
- Ask for username and password for login:

  - [`get_login_async(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/asynchronous%20functions/get_login_async.html)
  - Show a message/question to the user:
  - [`show_message(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/debugging/show_message.html) and [`show_message_async(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/asynchronous%20functions/show_message_async.html)
  - [`show_question(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/debugging/show_question.html) and [`show_question_async(...);`](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/asynchronous%20functions/show_question_async.html)

Read more [here](http://gamemaker.info/en/manual/407_02_messages).